# Drag and drop. Nudging other images while moving

Tags: objective-c

I've implemented drag and drop for multiple images which works fine but I'm facing one issue. When I'm dragging one image, other images will be nudged along when my finger moves over them whilst Im still dragging the original image. I'd love to be able to have only one image moveable at once.

Heres some of my code.

```
-(void)touchesBegan: (NSSet *) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];

   for (UIImageView *noseImage in noseArray) {

       if ([touch.view isEqual:noseArray]) {

           firstTouchPoint = [touch locationInView:[self view]];
           xd = firstTouchPoint.x - [[touch view]center].x;
           yd = firstTouchPoint.y - [[touch view]center].y;

       }
    }
 }

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint oldPoint = [touch previousLocationInView:touch.view];
CGPoint newPoint = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
CGPoint diff = CGPointMake(newPoint.x - oldPoint.x, newPoint.y - oldPoint.y);

     for (UIImageView *noseImageView in noseArray) {

         if (CGRectContainsPoint(noseImageView.frame, newPoint)) {
             CGPoint cntr = [noseImageView center];
             [noseImageView setCenter:CGPointMake(cntr.x + diff.x, cntr.y + diff.y)];

         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you would determine which image is being dragged in the `touchesBegan:` and remember that. Then in the `touchesMoved:`, move the remembered image the given amount.

But a Gesture Recogniser works a lot easier than these low level methods, so I suggest you use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
 for (UIImageView *noseImage in noseArray) {

       if ([touch.view isEqual:noseArray]) {
```

Are you sure the second line shouldn't be the following?

```
if ([touch.view isEqual: noseImage]) {
```

Comment: Unfortunately I've already tried changing that line to what you suggested before and it doesn't change anything.